How to auto-mount (encrypted) partitions of an USB stick using udev and systemd
I have the following requirements:

If a particular USB stick is inserted, it should be automatically detected and mounted. The information where it must be mounted will be in /etc/fstab (of course).
If the USB stick is janked out, a full cleanup must automatically happen; resulting in having no lingering traces like that it was mounted (or still is mounted) and/or any non-finished systemd units.
If the partition(s) in question are manually umount-ed then also everything should be cleaned up, even though the stick is still present; removing it from the plug should clean up only that what could not be cleaned up before (likely the .device units).

In order to achieve the above in a clean manner, insertion of the USB stick should cause the start of a custom systemd unit, which we'll then configure to do the rest.
What is required to write this?
Lets assume we have an USB stick with three partitions:
/dev/sdc1 and /dev/sdc2 - which are LUKS encrypted,
and /dev/sdc3 - which is unencrypted.
For example,
>sudo blkid /dev/sdc{1,2,3}
/dev/sdc1: UUID="de9a000f-fa60-4050-8d11-864e97829b8a" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="219578f5-5905-41cd-895d-7b937ac0756a"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="012059c1-6b88-4937-889a-a21448740492" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="59c7f6f3-a5cb-41af-82fa-b515031d85d5"
/dev/sdc3: LABEL="README" UUID="9d262deb-2343-4096-bccf-bb26ed4415ad" BLOCK_SIZE="1024" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="165db3da-4ebb-4f59-ab09-ee5e5b26ed43"

Here UUID is what is used in /dev/disk/by-uuid:
>ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 22 18:27 012059c1-6b88-4937-889a-a21448740492 -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 22 18:27 9d262deb-2343-4096-bccf-bb26ed4415ad -> ../../sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 22 18:27 de9a000f-fa60-4050-8d11-864e97829b8a -> ../../sdc1

Since the device name /dev/sdc is rather random, we should only use the UUID from now on.
In order to manually mount the unencrypted partition we need to execute (make sure nothing is mounted on /mnt and/or /mnt/usb already!):
UUID=9d262deb-2343-4096-bccf-bb26ed4415ad
SERIAL=408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC
sudo /bin/mkdir -p /mnt/usb/$SERIAL/part3
sudo mount -t ext2 /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID /mnt/usb/$SERIAL/part3

Where I did choose to use the value of ID_SERIAL_SHORT of the usb device, which one can obtain with for example:
>udevadm info -n /dev/sdc3 | grep -E '(ID_SERIAL_SHORT|ID_FS_UUID)='
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC
E: ID_FS_UUID=9d262deb-2343-4096-bccf-bb26ed4415ad

Lets store the mount point in /etc/fstab by adding to that file:
UUID=9d262deb-2343-4096-bccf-bb26ed4415ad   /mnt/usb/408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC/part3 ext2    rw,noauto   0 0

Note that after that, we can do:
sudo mount /dev/sdc3

and it will do the mount just fine as long as that block device has the expected UUID.
The other two partitions, /dev/sdc{1,2} are encrypted and first need
UUID1=573bfda0-69f5-4fb9-9d7e-333a70a51710
UUID2=6d7bdc1d-3eb0-4774-a9fb-3d1ac1027010
echo $LUKS_PASS | sudo cryptsetup -q luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID1 usb-$UUID1
echo $LUKS_PASS | sudo cryptsetup -q luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID2 usb-$UUID2

to be executed, where I assume that the environment variable LUKS_PASS contains the passphrase required to decrypt the LUKS partition. The UUID's here are the ones that blkid returns:
>sudo blkid /dev/sdc{1,2}
/dev/sdc1: UUID="573bfda0-69f5-4fb9-9d7e-333a70a51710" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="caa57a9d-7389-4990-a243-34b19a179368"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="6d7bdc1d-3eb0-4774-a9fb-3d1ac1027010" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="10813450-6dcc-4700-9e88-d0577c0c9aeb"

This creates a /dev/mapper/usb-$UUID device (for each partition), each with its own UUID:
>sudo blkid /dev/mapper/usb*
/dev/mapper/usb-573bfda0-69f5-4fb9-9d7e-333a70a51710: LABEL="gold1-2024-12-21" UUID="67f056be-dbbc-4f7a-979d-6ff077d16e93" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/mapper/usb-6d7bdc1d-3eb0-4774-a9fb-3d1ac1027010: LABEL="gold2-2024-12-21" UUID="94bfcc55-6b52-431f-bc76-3aa198c107c7" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext2"

And it's those UUIDs that we want to add to /etc/fstab.
To make life easier I wrote the following script that prints the required /etc/fstab configuration when run after inserting an USB (for my specific case, that is):
# Get the device path.
DEVPATH=$(/bin/ls /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler* | grep -E -v -- '-part[0-9]+$')
# Get the serial of the USB stick.
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=$(udevadm info -n $DEVPATH | grep ID_SERIAL_SHORT | sed -e 's/.*ID_SERIAL_SHORT=//')
# Run over all existing partitions.
for p in $(/bin/ls $DEVPATH-part*); do
  # Extract the "part?" string.
  PART=$(echo $p | sed -r -e 's/.*-(part[0-9]+)$/\1/')
  # Get the UUID of the block device of this partition iff it is a LUKS encrypted partition.
  UUID=$(blkid --match-token TYPE=crypto_LUKS $p | sed -e 's/.* UUID="\([^ ]*\)".*/\1/' || true)
  if [ -n "$UUID" ]; then
    # Decrypt the partition.
    echo $LUKS_PASS | sudo cryptsetup -q luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID usb-$UUID
    # Get the UUID of the encrypted partition.
    UUID2=$(blkid /dev/mapper/usb-$UUID | sed -e 's/.* UUID="\([^ ]*\)".*/\1/')
    echo -e "UUID=$UUID2\t/mnt/usb/$ID_SERIAL_SHORT/$PART\text2\trw,noauto\t0 0"
    sudo cryptsetup luksClose usb-$UUID
  else
    # Get UUID of non-encrypted partition.
    UUID=$(blkid $p | sed -e 's/.* UUID="\([^ ]*\)".*/\1/')
    echo -e "UUID=$UUID\t/mnt/usb/$ID_SERIAL_SHORT/$PART\text2\trw,noauto\t0 0"
  fi
done

After exporting LUKS_PASS make sure to run the above script using sudo -E to preserve the environment. Example output:
>sudo -E ./foo.sh
UUID=db97c4b0-8f92-4edc-bacb-dc90e62de2e2       /mnt/usb/408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC/part1 ext2    rw,noauto       0 0
UUID=c45c6a7a-1c0f-49c4-bcfb-15766114daa1       /mnt/usb/408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC/part2 ext2    rw,noauto       0 0
UUID=9d262deb-2343-4096-bccf-bb26ed4415ad       /mnt/usb/408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC/part3 ext2    rw,noauto       0 0

With /etc/fstab set up and knowing exactly what commands are needed; what is left is to automate this with udev and systemd units.
The question is: how?

Note that I intend to answer my own question, after extensively researching what is the correct way to do this. I've already spent two days on this and because I can't find good documentation I decided to get to the bottom of this myself and then contribute this to the community by means of a post on stackexchange.

This answer is written after I solved the problem (as opposed to writing it while I was doing all the research).
systemd already supports mounting encrypted filesystems out of the box.
The following points are required:

A new udev rule to trigger a custom template service unit.
A custom service to trigger systemd's mount unit.
An entry in /etc/fstab for each partition, from which systemd-fstab-generator will generate the required mount unit.
An entry in /etc/crypttab for each partition that is encrypted, from which systemd-cryptsetup-generator will generate the required systemd-cryptsetup@.service template unit.

While implementing this we have to take into account that udev rules and systemd escape functionality do not play well together. We need to avoid the use of backslashes or it either won't work or will break in the near future when these bugs are fixed.
The custom service is only required because a mount unit can not be a template.
The udev rule
The udev rule can contain tests like ATTR{removable}=="1". To get a full list of possible ATTR tests, run:
sudo udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/sdc1

where /dev/sdc1 is the device path of a currently inserted USB stick partition.
Likewise, one can get a list of possible ENV{<property name>}=="<regular expression>" values with:
sudo udevadm info --query=property --export --name=/dev/sdc1

which will list lines as ID_SERIAL_SHORT='408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70'.
For example, my /etc/udev/rules.d/69-gold-usb.rules contains:
# Detect insertion of any of the three "Kingston DataTravel SE9 G3 64GB" USB security sticks.
SUBSYSTEMS=="block", \
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", \
ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="408D5CBECBBDE7C0E9160666|408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70|408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC", \
ACTION=="add", \
IMPORT{program}="/usr/local/sbin/udev-gold-usb-systemd_wants.sh $env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}-part$env{PARTN}"

# Added 28 December 2024.
# After changing this file run: sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

And yes, you can use backslashes to split up long lines. Just don't forget to use == (not =) and don't forget the comma's.
Note that this rule uses IMPORT{program} which is currently (December 2024) the only way to pass double backslashes to a SYSTEMD_WANTS property, but as the behavior of systemd is going to change in that regard (no longer requiring double backslashes), we shouldn't be using backslashes. This means that we can use slashes ('/' for  paths) which are converted to a hyphen ('-'), but we can't use a hypen ('-' as appear in UUIDs) which would be escaped as '\x2d'.
The script /usr/local/sbin/udev-gold-usb-systemd_wants.sh contains:
#! /bin/sh
echo "SYSTEMD_WANTS=mount-gold@$1.service"

and we are passing to it something like 408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70-part1 where the hypen is an escaped '/'! This string therefore must be used as, and thus exist, as part of a path that contains "408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70/part1" or it can't work.
Don't forget to run
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

to re-read all udev rules after you made changes.
The template service mount-gold@.service
As said before, this custom service is only required to allow the udev rule to have a variable path (although, I copied the idea from here without really testing if we can't specify the .mount directly).
For the rest is does nothing, but a StartExec is required. Therefore this unit file contains:
[Unit]
Description=Mount Gold USB device /mnt/usb/%I.
Requires=mnt-usb-%i.mount
After=mnt-usb-%i.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true

And as .mount unit files use their mount point as name, this means that this specifies the mount point as /mnt/usb/408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70/part1!
Fortunately we don't have to create that directory ourselves, see below.
The /etc/fstab entry.
/etc/fstab can contain entries that will cause systemd to generate .mount unit files, normally at boot time, but you can re-trigger this by running:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Here is an example of what is in my /etc/fstab:
UUID=5b214986-7db3-439c-99ba-f4da0cebdf34       /mnt/usb/408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70/part1 ext2    rw,noauto,noatime,x-mount.mkdir,x-systemd.requires=systemd-cryptsetup@usba52ee8f0a8fa42008c19d798303ac118.service       0 0
UUID=a3c7ffb6-3883-42a9-a880-e51f10e69f30       /mnt/usb/408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70/part2 ext2    rw,noauto,noatime,x-mount.mkdir,x-systemd.requires=systemd-cryptsetup@usb47553f64e4b14ad189e273133bdaa65d.service       0 0
UUID=046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754       /mnt/usb/408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70/part3 ext2    rw,noauto,noatime,x-mount.mkdir 0 0

Note how this contains the same mount point path /mnt/usb/408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70/part1, otherwise it wouldn't cause the generation of the mnt-usb-408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70-part1.mount unit.
The first column, UUID=5b214986-7db3-439c-99ba-f4da0cebdf34, contains the UUID of the partition that must be mounted: the decrypted /dev/mapper/usba52ee8f0a8fa42008c19d798303ac118, not the encrypted /dev/sdc1 partition. x-mount.mkdir causes the mount point path to be automatically created if it doesn't exist. And x-systemd.requires=systemd-cryptsetup@usba52ee8f0a8fa42008c19d798303ac118.service makes sure that cryptsetup is being run first in order to create that decrypted /dev/mapper/usba52ee8f0a8fa42008c19d798303ac118 that we want to mount.
Also note that partition 3 is not encrypted, so 046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754 is the UUID of /dev/sdc3 and that line doesn't have a x-systemd.requires=.
The /etc/crypttab entry.
For the encrypted partitions to work, we also need an entry in /etc/crypttab:
usba52ee8f0a8fa42008c19d798303ac118     /dev/disk/by-uuid/a52ee8f0-a8fa-4200-8c19-d798303ac118  none    luks,noauto
usb47553f64e4b14ad189e273133bdaa65d     /dev/disk/by-uuid/47553f64-e4b1-4ad1-89e2-73133bdaa65d  none    luks,noauto

Here /dev/disk/by-uuid/a52ee8f0-a8fa-4200-8c19-d798303ac118 is the encrypted partition (it points to /dev/sdc1) and usba52ee8f0a8fa42008c19d798303ac118 is a random id, which as it turns out, can not contain backslashes [...]. In order to avoid collisions I used the UUID, but had to remove the hypens from it.
Entering the pass phrase to unlock the LUKS partitions.
With the above in place and having reloaded the configs (see above), inserting the USB stick will send a broadcast message to all tty's with something like:
Broadcast message from root@<your host name> (Sun 2024-12-29 16:46:37 CET):

Password entry required for '<some description>' (PID 281235).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool.

Just hit Enter to see your prompt again (assuming it was still empty and your weren't in the middle of typing), and run:
sudo systemd-tty-ask-password-agent

This will then allow you to enter whatever secret is required.
If the USB contains more than one partition, but have the same pass phrase, then you only have to enter it once (the second one will try the last entered pass phrase first and since that works won't require you to enter it again). I didn't test what happens if they have a different pass phrase, I can imagine that in that case you have a problem; maybe need to run sudo systemd-tty-ask-password-agent again after a failure or something like that.
Using a YubiKey
Install the package libfido2. Then, with your YubiKey inserted, run:
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --fido2-device=auto /dev/sdc1

(and afterwards for all other encrypted partitions, of course).
This will ask you to enter the passphrase of /dev/sdc1, then it will ask for the FIDO2 PIN. If you didn't change that yet, it will be the default 123456.
You can change this PIN with the following command:
sudo ykman fido access change-pin

Doesn't matter if you do this before or after. It has no effect on the FIDO credentials.
You can inspect the result with
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdc1

This now should show one more key under Keyslots:, at the very least the one containing your pass phrase, but also a new one.
Under Tokens: you will see an entry with systemd-fido2, and a reference to the Keyslot that it uses.
To make the system use the YubiKey, change the entries in your /etc/crypttab to contain fido2-device=auto. For example,
usba52ee8f0a8fa42008c19d798303ac118     /dev/disk/by-uuid/a52ee8f0-a8fa-4200-8c19-d798303ac118  none    luks,noauto,fido2-device=auto

and rerun sudo systemctl daemon-reload.
If now you insert the USB key it should do a broadcast message as before, but if then you run sudo systemd-tty-ask-password-agent it will ask for Please enter LUKS2 token PIN:. Enter the PIN that you set (or still 123456) and then tap your YubiKey once for every partition that needs to be decrypted.
Now your partitions should be mounted. If they are not mounted then you are in deep shit because I didn't explain anything, I just hand-held you with the final answer :(. Expect many days of reading documents and learning all kinds of commands to find out intermediate results and debug output (e.g. journalctl -b -t systemd). Asking an A.I. for help with learning these commands actually helps here.
Finally, here is a little script that I used to print the required entries for /etc/fstab and /etc/crypttab, because that is a lot of work and I had three of these USB sticks (in case of failure of one in the future):
# Get the device path.
DEVPATH=$(/bin/ls /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler* | grep -E -v -- '-part[0-9]+$')
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=$(udevadm info -n $DEVPATH | grep ID_SERIAL_SHORT | sed -e 's/.*ID_SERIAL_SHORT=//')
echo "/etc/fstab:"
for p in $(/bin/ls $DEVPATH-part*); do
  PART=$(echo $p | sed -r -e 's/.*-(part[0-9]+)$/\1/')
  UUID=$(blkid --match-token TYPE=crypto_LUKS $p | sed -e 's/.* UUID="\([^ ]*\)".*/\1/' || true)
  if [ -n "$UUID" ]; then
    MAPPERID=$(echo "usb$UUID" | sed -e 's/-//g')
    echo $LUKS_PASS | sudo cryptsetup -q luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID $MAPPERID 2>/dev/null
    UUID2=$(blkid /dev/mapper/$MAPPERID | sed -e 's/.* UUID="\([^ ]*\)".*/\1/')
    ID_FS_TYPE=$(udevadm info -n /dev/mapper/$MAPPERID | grep 'ID_FS_TYPE=' | sed -e 's/.*ID_FS_TYPE=//')
    echo -e "UUID=$UUID2\t/mnt/usb/$ID_SERIAL_SHORT/$PART\t$ID_FS_TYPE\trw,noauto,noatime,x-mount.mkdir,x-systemd.requires=systemd-cryptsetup@$MAPPERID.service\t0 0"
    sudo cryptsetup luksClose $MAPPERID 2>/dev/null
  else
    UUID=$(blkid $p | sed -e 's/.* UUID="\([^ ]*\)".*/\1/')
    ID_FS_TYPE=$(udevadm info -n $p | grep 'ID_FS_TYPE=' | sed -e 's/.*ID_FS_TYPE=//')
    echo -e "UUID=$UUID\t/mnt/usb/$ID_SERIAL_SHORT/$PART\t$ID_FS_TYPE\trw,noauto,noatime,x-mount.mkdir\t0 0"
  fi
done
echo "/etc/crypttab:"
for p in $(/bin/ls $DEVPATH-part*); do
  PART=$(echo $p | sed -r -e 's/.*-(part[0-9]+)$/\1/')
  UUID=$(blkid --match-token TYPE=crypto_LUKS $p | sed -e 's/.* UUID="\([^ ]*\)".*/\1/' || true)
  if [ -n "$UUID" ]; then
    MAPPERID=$(echo "usb$UUID" | sed -e 's/-//g')
    echo -e "$MAPPERID\t/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID\tnone\tluks,noauto,fido2-device=auto"
  fi
done


EDIT: TLDR; you want to read my other answer first.
Here is a step by step report on my research.
Debug logging
There might be a better way, but the following works:
I created an executable script in /usr/local/sbin/log_service with the following content:
#! /bin/sh
echo "$1 : \"$2\""

When this is run using /bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest it will write output written to stdout by the script to the journal.
To monitor the output we therefore run, in a separate terminal window:
journalctl -b -t systemd -t usbtest -f

to monitor output in real-time.
Fake .device
First I created a fake service that I will use as a fake ".device" (although this is a .service).
Create the following file as /etc/systemd/system/A.service:
[Unit]
Description=A fake device (service A)

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service A start
ExecStop=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service A stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and then run sudo systemctl daemon-reload to make the running systemd aware of it.
Try to start the new service:
sudo systemctl start A

This results in the immediate log output:
Dec 23 14:20:16 daniel systemd[1]: Started A fake device (service A).
Dec 23 14:20:16 daniel usbtest[1583423]: A : "start"
Dec 23 14:20:16 daniel usbtest[1583428]: A : "stop"
Dec 23 14:20:16 daniel systemd[1]: A.service: Deactivated successfully.

The reason being that the script that is being run (/usr/local/sbin/log_service) immediately returns.
Since instead we want to mimic a service that we can start and stop through systemctl, we add the line RemainAfterExit=yes:
[Unit]
Description=A fake device (service A)
Wants=B.service         # See below.

[Service]
Type=oneshot            # See below.
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service A start
ExecStop=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service A stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Now we can sudo systemctl start A and separately sudo systemctl stop A.
Fake mount .service
Lets do this again for a new service B. The idea is that we want that B is started automatically when A is started, and stopping A must cause B to be stopped. Stopping B manually however, should not stop A.
Because B is going to be a dependent of A and both do logging, we want B to be started after A finished logging (the ExecStart of A finished), therefore change A.service again and add Type=oneshot; we want to ensure all ExecStart's are done before any dependent services start. Note that another difference is that with type oneshot, if there are multiple ExecStart lines, they are done sequentially and the next is only started after the previous one finished as opposed to Type=simple, the default, which starts all ExecStart lines in parallel (because they are not expected to finish quickly, or at all). However, that is of no concern to us: we only have a single ExecStart (one that does return "immediately", otherwise you can't use oneshot).
I won't repeat everything I tried here; just the end result that works:
[Unit]
Description=Fake mount service (service B)
After=A.service
Requisite=A.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service B start
ExecStop=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service B stop

[Install]
WantedBy=A.service

(don't forget to rerun sudo systemctl daemon-reload).
That we need After=A.service speaks for itself: you can't mount a device if that doesn't exist (aka, the .device unit is active); hence we don't want to start B until after A was started.
In order to have B started whenever A is started, it is not sufficient to have the WantedBy=A.service, we need to add Wants=B.service to the [Unit] section of A.service!
With that, B is started if we start A. We don't want A to be started if we try to start B: that doesn't make sense. Therefore we use Requisite=A.service as opposed to Requires=A.service (or BindsTo=A.service). As a result this neatly simply refuses to start B if A isn't active (as per the documentation):
>sudo systemctl start B
A dependency job for B.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.

instead of starting A.
We can also stop B once both are active; this only stops B (we can't even stop the .device, as that wouldn't make sense: it is still plugged in). Running systemctl start A after that (even though A is already active) does start B again, which is probably what we want.
Finally, stopping A while both are active stops first B and then A - exactly as we want. This is strange however because from the documentation I understand that this is a feature of BindsTo= that has the following description:

Configures requirement dependencies, very similar in style to Requires=. However, this dependency type is stronger: in addition to the effect of Requires= it declares that if the unit bound to is stopped, this unit will be stopped too. This means a unit bound to another unit that suddenly enters inactive state will be stopped too. Units can suddenly, unexpectedly enter inactive state for different reasons: the main process of a service unit might terminate on its own choice, the backing device of a device unit might be unplugged or the mount point of a mount unit might be unmounted without involvement of the system and service manager.

which describes exactly what we need ("a device unit might be unplugged").
While the documentation of Requisite= is

Similar to Requires=. However, if the units listed here are not started already, they will not be started and the starting of this unit will fail immediately. Requisite= does not imply an ordering dependency, even if both units are started in the same transaction. Hence this setting should usually be combined with After=, to ensure this unit is not started before the other unit.

So, we want this (starting B will fail if A isn't already started instead of trying to start B), but it doesn't mention the part of BindsTo that we also need (stopping A will stop B).
However, if I add BindsTo=A.service the function of Requisite= is nullified and starting B simply starts A (first). A bug in systemd (tested with version 257-1 on Arch)?
Using a real device (udev)
We can add an udev rule to detect the insertion of one of the USB sticks that I want to detect. Note that even without such a rule, inserting an USB stick already causes .device units to be created:
>systemctl list-units --type=device | grep usb8
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:08.1-0000:0c:00.3-usb8-8\x2d4-8\x2d4.3-8\x2d4.3:1.0-host12-target12:0:0-12:0:0:0-block-sdc-sdc1.device loaded active plugged DataTraveler_3.0 1
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:08.1-0000:0c:00.3-usb8-8\x2d4-8\x2d4.3-8\x2d4.3:1.0-host12-target12:0:0-12:0:0:0-block-sdc-sdc2.device loaded active plugged DataTraveler_3.0 2
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:08.1-0000:0c:00.3-usb8-8\x2d4-8\x2d4.3-8\x2d4.3:1.0-host12-target12:0:0-12:0:0:0-block-sdc-sdc3.device loaded active plugged DataTraveler_3.0 README
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:08.1-0000:0c:00.3-usb8-8\x2d4-8\x2d4.3-8\x2d4.3:1.0-host12-target12:0:0-12:0:0:0-block-sdc.device      loaded active plugged DataTraveler_3.0

but because the names of those .device units might change (if only based on the location that I plug them in) we can't use their name the way we used A.service all over the place. Also, we need to add a Wants=B.service to these devices - which these don't have. And finally, we don't want to trigger B.service for just any USB device their partitions and their mother, but only for the partitions that I have listed above.
All of this can be achieved by creating a new udev rule.
While the usb stick is plugged in (which has a third partition /dev/sdc3) we can run for example:
>sudo udevadm test /sys/class/block/sdc3 2>/dev/null | grep -E '(DEVPATH|DEVNAME|ACTION|SUBSYSTEM|TAGS|ID_BUS|ID_SERIAL|DEVLINKS|SYSTEMD_WANTS)'
  DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb8/8-4/8-4.4/8-4.4:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc3
  DEVNAME=/dev/sdc3
  ACTION=add
  SUBSYSTEM=block
  TAGS=:systemd:
  ID_BUS=usb
  ID_SERIAL=Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70-0:0
  ID_SERIAL_SHORT=408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70
  DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-diskseq/115-part3 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0c:00.3-usb-0:4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part/by-partuuid/deb41f73-7955-4eba-8fac-2c7d01b93af4 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70-0:0-part3 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0c:00.3-usb-0:4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part/by-label/README /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0c:00.3-usb-0:4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3 /dev/disk/by-partuuid/deb41f73-7955-4eba-8fac-2c7d01b93af4 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0c:00.3-usbv3-0:4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0c:00.3-usb-0:4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part/by-partnum/3 /dev/disk/by-uuid/046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754 /dev/disk/by-label/README /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0c:00.3-usb-0:4.4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part/by-uuid/046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754
  CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:

Note how this tells us that udev is aware of everything (UUID and ID_SERIAL_SHORT in particular) but SYSTEMD_WANTS is not set. We need that to be set to B.service.
Next we create a new udev rule by creating the file /etc/udev/rules.d/69-gold-usb.rules with contents:
SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="408D5CBECBBDE7C0E9160666|408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70|408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="B.service"

And reload with sudo udevadm control --reload-rules.
When running sudo udevadm test /sys/class/block/sdc3 again (as above) we get the same result, but with one extra line:
>sudo udevadm test /sys/class/block/sdc3 2>/dev/null | grep -E '(DEVPATH|DEVNAME|ACTION|SUBSYSTEM|TAGS|ID_BUS|ID_SERIAL|DEVLINKS|SYSTEMD_WANTS)'
...
  SYSTEMD_WANTS=B.service

indicating that the rule works.
We can test the same thing by plugging and unplugging the USB stick while running
sudo udevadm monitor --property | grep -E '^UDEV.*(add|remove)|^SYSTEMD_WANTS' | grep -B1 SYSTEMD_WANTS

This gives, when adding the USB stick:
UDEV  [182604.679907] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb8/8-4/8-4.4/8-4.4:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
SYSTEMD_WANTS=B.service
UDEV  [182604.703373] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb8/8-4/8-4.4/8-4.4:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc2 (block)
SYSTEMD_WANTS=B.service
UDEV  [182604.705526] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb8/8-4/8-4.4/8-4.4:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1 (block)
SYSTEMD_WANTS=B.service
UDEV  [182604.708620] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb8/8-4/8-4.4/8-4.4:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc3 (block)
SYSTEMD_WANTS=B.service

and the the same with remove when unplugging.
Note how the rule gets triggered for both, /dev/sdc as well as each of the three partitions. Because we are only interested in the partitions, lets add ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition" to the udev rule:
SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="408D5CBECBBDE7C0E9160666|408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70|408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="B.service"

We now have an udev rule that detects insertion of one of the three USB sticks, and then as a result starts B.service. However B.service itself lacks the correct After=, Requisite= and WantedBy=, so that unplugging the USB stick does not has the desired effect yet.
Adding the dependency on the .device to B.service
If we'd have only one partition to deal with (say, /dev/sdc3 of this particular USB stick) then a straightforward way to add the dependency seems to use one of the DEVLINKS - most notably,
/dev/disk/by-uuid/046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754

which is, of course, entirely fixed for a given partition.
However, these path names must be escaped: all slashes must be replaced with dashes (-), and if we try:
Requisite=dev-disk-by-uuid-046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754.device

Then we get the following interesting error when B.service is started:
Dec 23 20:01:45 daniel systemd[1]: /dev/disk/by/uuid/046ba81b/7d9c/4a54/a69f/6fba06ac7754 is inactive.
Dec 23 20:01:45 daniel systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Fake mount service (service B).

Note how also the - that are part of the UUID were converted to /.
The correct way to generate this string is with
>systemd-escape dev/disk/by-uuid/046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754.device
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-046ba81b\x2d7d9c\x2d4a54\x2da69f\x2d6fba06ac7754.device

But, using this string in B.service instead of the string A.service reveals that B is not stopped if we unplug the USB stick (as expected by just looking at the documentation). Therefore, we do need to also add a BindsTo= line.
B.service then becomes:
[Unit]
Description=Fake mount service (service B)
After=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-046ba81b\x2d7d9c\x2d4a54\x2da69f\x2d6fba06ac7754.device
Requisite=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-046ba81b\x2d7d9c\x2d4a54\x2da69f\x2d6fba06ac7754.device
BindsTo=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-046ba81b\x2d7d9c\x2d4a54\x2da69f\x2d6fba06ac7754.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service B start
ExecStop=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service B stop

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-046ba81b\x2d7d9c\x2d4a54\x2da69f\x2d6fba06ac7754.device

Interestingly enough, now trying to start sudo systemctl start B doesn't fail, but it does hang if the USB is not plugged in, until you plug it in. That is kinda neat I guess.
Plugging the USB in automatically starts B anyway. At that point we can manually stop B as before, at which point B is stopped while the stick is plugged in and then we can just (re)start B manually without that it hangs.
We can pass just the (dynamic) UUID to the service, slightly as a hack, by doing:
ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="B@$env{ID_FS_UUID}.service"

and then use %i in the .service to access the UUID. I call this a "hack" because it only works because an UUID doesn't contain illegal character for an escaped string: you SHOULD pass a systemd escaped string here; in that case %i would be that escaped string and %I would be the original, unescaped string.
However, this is not usable: we NEED the escaped string for After=, Requisite=, BindsTo= and WantedBy= because there is no way to manipulate %i: it must be used as-is.
There is a way to create the escaped string during the udev rule, but due to a bug in udev it is impossible to actually use that if it contains any backslashes (it is beyond me how such a horrible bug can exist for years without anyone fixing it).
The only remaining option therefore is to use SYMLINK with a path that doesn't contain any characters that need to be escaped with a backslash (aka, no '-' characters). In fact, we can pass any information using this trick!
SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="408D5CBECBBDE7C0E9160666|408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70|408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC", PROGRAM="/usr/local/sbin/udev-escape '$env{ID_FS_UUID}'", SYMLINK+="usb/%c", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="B@usb-%c.service"

This way we can pass (any) information (in this case only ID_FS_UUID) while still using %i for the dependency stuff in the @.service template!
We only have to make sure that the %c, the output of PROGRAM (and thus the SYMLINK) does not contain any characters that need to be escaped or are escaped with a backslash.
The /usr/local/sbin/udev-escape that I use contains:
#! /bin/sh

# Utility to convert any string to something that will
# survive being passed through %c of an udev rule to
# a systemd service using SYSTEMD_WANTS.
# Written by Carlo Wood (Dec 2024).

echo "$1" | /usr/bin/base64 -w0 | /usr/bin/tr '+/=' '.:_'

Simple, but you have to admit, brilliant.
The counter part is /usr/local/sbin/udev-unescape:
#! /bin/sh

# Utility to decode string that were produced by udev-unescape.
# Carlo Wood (Dec 2024).

echo "$1" | /usr/bin/tr '.:_' '+/=' | /usr/bin/base64 -d

Warning: the output of this program can contain ANYTHING, including newline characters. So you should be very careful how to use it in a service, that is being run by root and stuff. Probably best to apply some filtering.
Using the above, %i is going to have a value like MDQ2YmE4MWItN2Q5Yy00YTU0LWE2OWYtNmZiYTA2YWM3NzU0Cg__.
The device path then is /dev/%I, or /dev/usb/MDQ2YmE4MWItN2Q5Yy00YTU0LWE2OWYtNmZiYTA2YWM3NzU0Cg__, which will be a symlink to for example /dev/sdc3. And inside the service scripts we can retrieve our information by passing %i to udev-unescape:
>udev-unescape MDQ2YmE4MWItN2Q5Yy00YTU0LWE2OWYtNmZiYTA2YWM3NzU0Cg__
046ba81b-7d9c-4a54-a69f-6fba06ac7754

Hence, B@.service now becomes:
[Unit]
Description=Fake mount service (service B)
After=dev-%i.device
Requisite=dev-%i.device
BindsTo=dev-%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service "%i" start
ExecStop=/bin/systemd-cat -t usbtest /usr/local/sbin/log_service "%I" stop

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-%i.device

Passing arbitrary information from udev to a service.
Udev has a lot of information available, it would be a waste not to pass that. With the USB stick inserted, you can now easily see which partitions are available:
>ls -l /dev/usb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Dec 24 15:58 MDQ2YmE4MWItN2Q5Yy00YTU0LWE2OWYtNmZiYTA2YWM3NzU0Cg__ -> ../sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Dec 24 15:58 NDc1NTNmNjQtZTRiMS00YWQxLTg5ZTItNzMxMzNiZGFhNjVkCg__ -> ../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Dec 24 15:58 YTUyZWU4ZjAtYThmYS00MjAwLThjMTktZDc5ODMwM2FjMTE4Cg__ -> ../sdc1

Lets say we want to investigate what information is available for sdc1.
We can list the ATTR values with:
>sudo udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdc1)
...
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb8/8-4/8-4.4/8-4.4:1.0/host12/targ>
    KERNEL=="sdc1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
...etc

And we can inspect the udev environment variables using - say:
>sudo udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/usb/YTUyZWU4ZjAtYThmYS00MjAwLThjMTktZDc5ODMwM2FjMTE4Cg__)
...
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/69-gold-usb.rules
...
sdc1: /etc/udev/rules.d/69-gold-usb.rules:2 Running PROGRAM="/usr/local/sbin/udev-escape 'a52ee8f0-a8fa-4200-8c19-d798303ac118'"
sdc1: Running in test mode, skipping execution of '/usr/local/sbin/udev-escape 'a52ee8f0-a8fa-4200-8c19-d798303ac118 crypto_LUKS''.
...
Properties:
  DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb8/8-4/8-4.4/8-4.4:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
  DEVNAME=/dev/sdc1
  DEVTYPE=partition
...
  ACTION=add
  SUBSYSTEM=block
  TAGS=:systemd:
  ID_BUS=usb
  ID_MODEL=DataTraveler_3.0
  ID_MODEL_ENC=DataTraveler\x203.0
  ID_MODEL_ID=1666
  ID_SERIAL=Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70-0:0
  ID_SERIAL_SHORT=408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70
...
  ID_TYPE=disk
  ID_FS_UUID=a52ee8f0-a8fa-4200-8c19-d798303ac118
  ID_FS_TYPE=crypto_LUKS
...
  SYSTEMD_WANTS=mount-gold@usb-.service

Note that SYSTEMD_WANTS has an empty %i because we never really did run udev-escape in this case.
We're going to need the value of ID_FS_TYPE too, so lets change the udev rule to its FINAL VERSION:
daniel:/etc/udev/rules.d>cat 69-gold-usb.rules
# Detect insertion of any of the three "Kingston DataTravel SE9 G3 64GB" USB security sticks.
SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="408D5CBECBBDE7C0E9160666|408D5CBF5F0AE7C0E9150B70|408D5CBECAC3E7C0E9170AEC", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/usr/local/sbin/udev-escape '$env{ID_FS_UUID} $env{ID_FS_TYPE}'", SYMLINK+="usb/%c", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="mount-gold@usb-%c.service"

# Added 22 December 2024.
# After changing this file run: sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

Here I added $env{ID_FS_TYPE} to the encoding of the symlink.
Adding auto-mounting
We're now done with udev. mount-gold@.service is started properly and we can pass any information (from udev) to it that we need.
To finish this project, lets rename B@.service to something normal and change it to call some real scripts.
What I did was create the file /etc/systemd/system/mount-gold@.service with the following content:
[Unit]
Description=Mount Gold USB device /dev/%I.
After=dev-%i.device
Requisite=dev-%i.device
BindsTo=dev-%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/usb-gold-start %i
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/usb-gold-stop %i

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-%i.device

This incorporates everything we learned about the unit file
leaving us only with the task of writing the scripts.
TODO
This answer is getting so long that I decided to post it already.
I'll make updates to the remaining parts once I got it fully working.
My current files are:
/usr/local/sbin/usb-gold-start:
#! /bin/sh

# Strip the leading "usb-" from the argument.
ENCODED_DATA=${1:4}
# Decode the data that was passed.
DATA="$(/usr/local/sbin/udev-unescape $ENCODED_DATA)"
# Extract the value of ID_FS_UUID (the first argument).
ID_FS_UUID=${DATA%%\ *}
# Extract the value of ID_FS_TYPE (the second argument).
ID_FS_TYPE=${DATA#*\ }
# Cache the block device path of the partition.
DEVPATH="/dev/disk/by-uuid/$ID_FS_UUID"

# Use /etc/fstab to mount the partition.
if [ "$ID_FS_TYPE" = "ext2" ]; then
  mount $DEVPATH
elif [ "$ID_FS_TYPE" = "crypto_LUKS" ]; then
  /usr/local/sbin/get-usb-gold-luks-pass | cryptsetup -q luksOpen $DEVPATH usb-$ID_FS_UUID
  mount $(blkid --output export /dev/mapper/usb-$ID_FS_UUID | grep '^UUID=')
fi

/usr/local/sbin/usb-gold-stop:
#! /bin/sh

# Strip the leading "usb-" from the argument.
ENCODED_DATA=${1:4}
# Decode the data that was passed.
DATA="$(/usr/local/sbin/udev-unescape $ENCODED_DATA)"
# Extract the value of ID_FS_UUID (the first argument).
ID_FS_UUID=${DATA%%\ *}
# Extract the value of ID_FS_TYPE (the second argument).
ID_FS_TYPE=${DATA#*\ }

ACTION=stop

echo $1 > /tmp/"$ACTION"_$ID_FS_UUID
echo $ENCODED_DATA >> /tmp/"$ACTION"_$ID_FS_UUID
echo $DATA >> /tmp/"$ACTION"_$ID_FS_UUID
echo $ID_FS_UUID >> /tmp/"$ACTION"_$ID_FS_UUID
echo $ID_FS_TYPE >> /tmp/"$ACTION"_$ID_FS_UUID

if [ "$ID_FS_TYPE" = "ext2" ]; then
  # Nothing to be done: it is already unmounted by the time the service is stopping.
  #umount /dev/disk/by-uuid/$ID_FS_UUID
  true
fi

EDIT (28 December 2024):
It turned out that also the SYMLINK trick can't be used, because that ".device" is killed during the cryptsetup, causing the .service to be terminated before cryptsetup returns. The latter still gets the chance to finish what it is doing, but mounting afterwards is a no-go.
Therefore, we need(ed) another method: One can use IMPORT{program} which preserves backslashes. For example: IMPORT{program}="/usr/local/sbin/udev-gold-usb-systemd_wants.sh $env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}-part$env{PARTN}", in which case it is theoretically possible to write double backslashes to the output of udev-gold-usb-systemd_wants.sh which then become single backslashes. However, this is deprecated because it has been decided (I think) that this 8-year-old bug just has to be fixed (see the previous link to the systemd issue; which has considerably grown since I added it). For the time being, it is best to stay away from trying to pass backslashes completely.
